# 405 Method not allowed exception for ie when launched from webdriver

Tags: jquery, selenium, https, selenium-webdriver

when i am launching ie from webdriver, and clicking on save, it gives me "405 Method not allowed" exception, but same works fine if i launch ie manually and click on save.

not sure why it is happening, any guesses..?

Answer (score 0):

You must enable profile, for Firefox it looks like that:

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox, :profile => "my-existing-profile")
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm using linux and i haven't ie. But you try to use DesiredCapabilities. There is big documentation for this.